# Ember.js belongsTo loading undefined models

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a model in ember that looks like so in part:

```
opt1votes: DS.hasMany('subscriber'),
opt2votes: DS.hasMany('subscriber'),
opt3votes: DS.hasMany('subscriber'),
opt4votes: DS.hasMany('subscriber'),
opt5votes: DS.hasMany('subscriber'),
keyword: DS.belongsTo('keyword'),
winAttachment: DS.belongsTo('asset'),
followAttachment: DS.belongsTo('asset'),
attachment: DS.belongsTo('asset'),
```

The issue comes up when this model doesn't have id's assigned to winAttachment, followAttachment and attachment properties (these are optional in the system). Instead of not loading anything for these properties ember is reaching out to our api and getting this response:

```
{"asset":[]}
```

This is causing 3 "asset" models to be created with "undefined" as all properties: http://screencloud.net/v/nZDD

My Question is why is ember loading without an id and how can it be stopped? Should I be returning something different for empty model requests so that ember knows the model is incomplete?

All help is appreciated!

EDIT: Original JSON from object:

```
{
  "campaign": [
    {
      "id": 360,
      "name": "aa test",
      "message": "Thanks",
      "followMessage": "",
      "followTime": "",
      "opt1": "",
      "opt2": "",
      "opt3": "",
      "opt4": "",
      "opt5": "",
      "opt1votes": [],
      "opt2votes": [],
      "opt3votes": [],
      "opt4votes": [],
      "opt5votes": [],
      "singleEntry": false,
      "winnerNumber": "",
      "winningMessage": "",
      "winners": [],
      "tagIds": "",
      "campaignType": "Response",
      "starred": false,
      "draft": false,
      "completed": false,
      "archived": false,
      "optins": 0,
      "optouts": 0,
      "keyword": 352,
      "paused": false,
      "startDate": 1396475400,
      "startDateDisplay": "Apr 02, 2014 4:50PM",
      "percentComplete": 0,
      "created": "Wednesday, Apr 2 2014 4:49PM",
      "attachment": "",
      "followAttachment": "",
      "winAttachment": "",
      "entryQuota": 0,
      "createdSorting": 1396475366,
      "subLists": "",
      "subs": "",
      "endCampaign": false,
      "pageUrl": "http://l.gocella.com/T1d0NM5",
      "sentAllTime": 0,
      "sentThirtyDays": 0,
      "sentNinetyDays": 0,
      "votesAllTime": 0,
      "votesThirtyDays": 0,
      "votesNinetyDays": 0,
      "entriesAllTime": 0,
      "entriesThirtyDays": 0,
      "entriesNinetyDays": 0,
      "followsSentAllTime": 0,
      "followsSentThirtyDays": 0,
      "followsSentNinetyDays": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

This object then has the belongsTo relationships in the model

Comment: can you show the original json that's being returned?

Comment: Can you make a jsbin of this? I would suspect it may nbe a problem in some of the code you do not show here?

Comment: @kingpin2k Yes, I have put it in the question as it is too long for comments

Comment: You will see the "attachment":"","followAttachment":"","winAttachment":"" in the JSON. We are not sending back ID's however ember is attempting to load them resulting in "undefined"

Comment: We were able to get these empty models to stop loading into our dropdown menus by filtering out any that do not have an ID, but ember is still trying to find them with no ID present. It doesn't do this on any other properties that have a relationship but have no ID.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you're leaving those properties out of your JSON, causing their values to be `'undefined'` when coerced to a string, which Ember-Data thinks is a valid ID. Ember-Data expects those properties in your JSON, and it expects valid values for them, whether your system considers them optional or not. You should be including those three properties in your JSON, and setting them to `null` if the relationship doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks @GJK but my question is why is ember attempting to load these belongsTo models when there is no ID present on the original JSON (editied into question above)? I did attempt to return "null" for these properties but it does a request looking for an ID of "null"

Comment: If you're returning `null` (not as a string but the value), and Ember-Data is still trying to fetch the object, then you've found an Ember-Data bug.

Comment: Yeah I am thinking so... we are returning an empty value or null value and ember is still trying to grab the model by referencing no ID.